# Substring removal and replacement in PowerShell in ps file

Tags: powershell

I have .TXT file which has 100 statements as below with name of DLL and `\\AS\ABC_1\CD` changing in each line

```
-MASSFile=x.dll,\\AS\ABC_1\CD\software\DDD\x.dll
```

The `\\AS\ABC_1\CD` is not constant and changes on daily basis.What is constant is the dll name.

So in powershell script I want to search by name x.dll which exists twice in each line and replace `\\AS\ABC_1\CD` with `..\..\LX` between the two .Dll names

so final statement is as below

```
-MASSFile=x.dll,..\..\LX\software\DDD\x.dll
```

Comment: Show your code and we can help you with your problems. But no one will write the script for you

Comment: Both name of .Dll and \\AS\ABC_1\CD changes in each line.What i know is the name of .Dll to search in text file .Each .Dll name exists twice in each line of text file.What i finally need is to change the path of dll,(the existing path in text file  i am not aware, but content after change i am aware

Comment: Getting error The process cannot access the file x.txt  because it is being used by another process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-replace` with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$line = '-MASSFile=x.dll,\\AS\ABC_1\CD\software\DDD\x.dll'
$dllName = 'x.dll'
$newPath = '\\server\share\path\to'

$line -replace ('(?<=={0},).+(?=\\{0}$)' -f [regex]::escape($dllName)), $newPath
```

The above yields:

```
-MASSFile=x.dll,\\server\share\path\to\x.dll
```

---

In order to perform the above replacement for all lines of a file and update that file in place, combine `Get-Content` with `ForEach-Object` and `Set-Content`:

```
$fileToUpdate = 'file.txt'
$dllName = 'x.dll'
$newPath = '\\server\share\path\to'

(Get-Content $fileToUpdate) | ForEach-Object { 
  $_ -replace ('(?<=={0},).+(?=\\{0}$)' -f [regex]::escape($dllName)), $newPath
} | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $fileToUpdate
```

- Note the need to enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)` to ensure that it is read *in full*, *up front*, which is required if you want to write the results back to the same file.
- `Set-Content` with an explicit `-Encoding` value ensures that the desired character encoding is used on output; if you're content with "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoding, you can use `> $fileToUpdate` instead of the `Set-Content` call.

Comment: Getting Error The process cannot access the file x.txt because it is being used by another process

Comment: @RAGHAV123: That suggests that you forgot to enclose the `Get-Content` command in `(...)`, as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
get-content $filepath | 
%{$_.Replace("\\AS\ABC_1\CD","..\..\LX")}  |
Set-Content $filepath
```

If you only want to change it on files named `x.dll`, you can change the replace method to:

```
$_.Replace("x.dll,\\AS\ABC_1\CD","x.dll,..\..\LX")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but the issue is \\AS\ABC_1\CD is not constant ,it will change on everyday basis.But what is constant is the name of the dll and "..\..\LX".So path between two keywords(i.e dll name existing twice in string) is to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$yourfile="c:\temp\test.txt"
(get-content "$yourfile").Replace("x.dll,\\AS\ABC_1\CD","x.dll,..\..\LX") | set-content $yourfile
```